# How do you query the session name and ID number via ASP>

Tags: c#, asp.net, server

With the command prompt it is possible to query the sessions for a server, as shown here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/query-session).

With an ***aspx file*** you can get a unique sessin ID by using:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID
```

Also, with an ***aspx file*** you can get the IP address by using:

```
Request.UserHostAddress
```

Is it possible with an ***aspx file*** to obtain the **session name** (e.g. console, rdp-tcp#10) and the corresponding  **ID** number (integer)?  I am trying to integrate an old piece of software that records a terminal/server ID number as part of key to record a user's request in a database.

Background:
I have a file with the extension ***.aspx*** from around ~2011 that integrates an enterprise database with software delivered by a web browser (software as a service?).  This file contains a call to `Request["sessionId"]` which I don't think returns anything as the key **"sessionId"** may nolonger be supportted?  For the file logic, all I need to know is whether the user has the "console" session type or not.  This aspx file is called by a batch file whenever a user presses one of the buttons on the enterprise database.

Comment: ASP.NET does start sessions when it receives requests through HTTP protocol with no RDP whatsoever and on a fixed port (the one configured in the web server). It is unclear to me your comparision because at the server side (the ASP.NET process) there is no information on the client side that started the communication other than the provided through HTTP.

Comment: I think you are confusing different kinds of sessions here. The asp.net session is not the same as a RDP session. I don't see that they would know the properties of each other.

Comment: I added some background to my question as by the comments from bradbury9 and mortb I am not confident that I asked the right question.